# How often should I update login cookies?

Tags: php

I haven’t written the code yet, as I am new to using cookies and trying to wrap my mind around the concept of coding cookies.  I’m going to be combing the use of cookies and session data for my login system.

*Because there is a time limit set in my cookies, I would think this would need to be updated periodically to keep the cookie active.*

**My plan:**

1. User Logs in
2. Cookies are set for user ID, a random token, and a random serial key, and IP address (should I include the IP?)
3. Cookie data is stored in a database for when cookie is retrieved to validate the information.

***I’m setting cookies to be valid for 1 month.***

---

**How often should cookie data be updated and when would you recommend updating it?**

- Should I update every time the server checks to see if user is logged
  in or should it be sparatic?  Should it only be updated if a session
  isn’t found and it checks for cookie validity?

***I’m new to this, so any info would be helpful before I start writing this code.***

Comment: Cookies are sent with each request, so why not check them every time? Also, I only store the random token in the cookie, by matching that with the tokens in the database I retrieve the other details, like user id, etc. This prevents any manipulation of those details.

Comment: Any benefit of using random token and random serial (basically a second token).  Wouldnt that help more with security by having two random numbers the system has to validate?

Comment: It's the complexity, or more accurately the informational load, of the random number that determines its security. A random number of 16 digits followed by a random serial of 16 digits has therefore, more or less, the same security as a random number of 32 digits. I say 'more or less' because the word 'serial' does imply its not completely random, and if that is detectable then it is not as secure as a completely random number.

Comment: so as far as the time set in the cookie, how often should that be updated and when would you recommend updating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest a framework for developing anything in php and I wouldn't try to re-invent the wheel with things like cookies, when frameworks have code to deal with them already - be that Laravel, Codeigniter (in any order).

Setting the cookie for a month should be optional - i.e. give your user the choice whether this is a one time login, otherwise their account may be at risk, say they're using a public computer.

The most simple form, is to update a database whenever a logged in user refreshes a page, based on the session, not the cookie. The cookie is editable client-side, therefore should not be relied on for this updating mechanism. It can be trusted more so for the "remember me" feature, because you can assign specific user ID's to specific tokens/cookie data, meaning that you can then check to see an exact match, if not that means that somebody has tampered with the cookie.

I wouldn't recommend doing both - updating database and updating cookie. Set the cookie once, on login, then just play with a session database.

Not sure I would trust the IP, bearing in mind your IP can now be spoofed and changed via external software, on top of a simple router restart which may assign new IP's on re-connection. It could be an option, but it cannot be the only basis of authentication.

---

example from comments, clarification:

Say I am a user with ID 1, who has a mobile phone, a tablet and a PC.
Cookies are default valid for 14 days from date and time of login and are only inserted once, and are never updated thereafter.

I have enabled the "remember me" feature on all 3 of my devices as I logged in today -

mobile phone - 17.04.2018 at 12:00
tablet - 17.04.2018 at 12.20
PC - 17.04.2018 at 12.30

We travel to the future, and we the date is now the 28.04.2018.

11 days have passed.

I enable the feature on a new device, my partners phone for example. 
The system should automatically remove the "stored" login from my mobile phone, even though 14 days haven't passed (because 3 is the maximum sessions that can be remembered per account).

---

The example I have provided only makes sense if you want to create a "secure" website which keeps control of not only active cookies but also of previous ones. Obviously, to be more secure I would't even give 3 remember me sessions, but only allow one or two.

If a limit is not what I was after, I would just give the user a settings page where they can deal with other active sessions on their account and give them the choice whether to remotely log those devices out or not.

Comment: I was planning on setting cookie based on a remember me checkbox.  And storing all other data in session.  I'm just trying to figure out how often I need to update the cookie time mainly.  Since it does have a time limit to it.  How often should that be updated?

Comment: A cookie time should be set on successful login, once and no more thereafter. It won't particularly matter if its set for 14 days or say 21 days, but I would assume the way to go is to make cookies last say 14 days and then clear previous saved cookies, if say there have been logins on new devices. Nobody needs more than a few "remember" me logins, we don't have 20,000 devices each ;)

Comment: So if a session is emptied and they come back to site.  The cookie is called.  A new session is created, and a new cookie is created.  And the old cookie is deleted.  Correct?

Comment: Basically yes, but I would allow a user to have (for example) 3 "remember me" sessions active at once and then you can simply backtrack through previous logins to make sure their accounts are secure and you aren't storing cookies from years ago which don't have any value to you.

Comment: What do you mean “backtrack through previous logins to make sure their accounts are secure”?

Comment: I will modify my answer with an example, because of the character count.